# Downloading VS 2012 ultimate - free?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

It appears that I can download Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate from this [Microsoft Site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30678), but I couldn't find any licensing related information (cost/keys etc) on that page.

Is Visual Studio 2012 free software?

Comment: There are free versions available for all aspects of ms design like C# and Web. They are called Express when they are free. However, the full version has all these installed and is not free, unless of course you're a student and your school can distribute full versions freely.

Comment: @BobbyDigital: That link seems to be the full version, and it seems to be free, from Microsoft... it's a great question actually, I'm really confused.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I followed it too and it does seem free. That's great. I already have it so I'm not going to go through the trouble of downloading and installing to only end up at an activation page saying please insert $$ :)

Comment: @BobbyDigital: Visual Studio 2012 has an activation page?

Comment: @Mehrdad: What I'm saying is, as the answer post says - it's likely "free" for now. Just like almost all other dev sw, Xamarin Studio pops into mind, you may be able to use some sw for a day, an hour, a year, or forever with some limitations that will make the sw useless to all but the weekend user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about purchasing a software tool, not using one.

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual Studio article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) notes the license type as:

> Express edition: [Registerware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registerware)
>   Other editions: [Trialware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trialware)

Not an authoritative source, I admit, but it would explain why it seems you can download it for free, because you actually have to register and pay (for the non-Express editions) at some point, or the trial would run out.

Comment: That is the way it's typically done.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, this isn't just a trial, but the main loss is not having an advanced MSDN membership.  There are certainly paid versions and subscriptions, but it looks like this is genuinely free, albeit without some added support and benefits.
See http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Visual-Studio-Professional-2012/productID.254639600 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/.  A couple quick Google searches uncover many people who are just as perplexed as to why Microsoft would do this.

Comment: One reason that pops into mind is the overwhelming idea that deving for ms is very costly. It could also be that 2013 about to come out and something very important is in it. VS2012 on win7 isn't capable, from what I understand, to do what 2012 does on a win8 machine.

Comment: I believe you can get VS2012 to work on Win7 with some limitations, but the 2013 Beta is already avilable for pre-release, so I think you're absolutely right; that could be a contributing factor.

Comment: Your right. I'm running VS2012 on win7 w/no limitations from *my* standpoint but that's because I'm not trying to dev for win8 specifically.